# Why doesn't \renewcommand{\ref}{\autoref} change \ref into \autoref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

First off, I'm very grateful of the help this community has provided me so far. Anyway, to my problem:

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I want...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\renewcommand{\ref}{\autoref}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Title} \label{anchor}
Blah Blah Blah. \ref{anchor}
\end{document}
```

to print as...

> 1 Section Title
>
> Blah Blah Blah. section 1

but instead I get ...

> 1 Section Title
>
> Blah Blah Blah. 1

... so `\ref` is not being replaced with `\autoref`. How can I correct this? Do I have no option but to do a *find-and-replace* to change `\ref` to `\autoref`?

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting.... I tried everything I know from `\renewcommand`, `\def`, `\let`, and `\LetLtxMacro`, but was not able to get `\ref` to produce the same output as `\autoref`.

Comment: I suggest you *not* to try this; `\ref` and `\autoref` are semantically different and using one or the other changes how the text is laid out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, figured out a solution:

[image]

### Notes:

- None of the usual tricks of using:

  1. `\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\autoref{#1}}`
  2. `\def\ref#1{\autoref{#1}}`
  3. `\let\ref\autoref`
  4. `\LetLtxMacro\ref\autoref`

  seem to work in this case.

  I suspect it is because `hyperref` does an `\AtBeginDocument`, so that some things get defined at the the start of the document. So using `\AtBeginDocument` puts our redefinition at the end of queue of commands that get executed `\AtBeginDocument`.

  And since placing the `\AtBeginDocument` to be before `\usepackage{hyperref}` does not work, this confirms that the suspicion was correct.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\autoref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section Title} \label{anchor}
Blah Blah Blah.  \autoref{anchor}  \ref{anchor}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or simply put the command after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @HarishKumar: But then that would be required in each document. Putting in the preamble is better in my opinion.

Comment: @PeterGrill: `\ref` is defined `\Hy@AtBeginDocument` - similar to `\AtBeginDocument`.